# Designer Not Implementing Interface Members

Tags: c#, winforms, interface, mvp

I'm writing a small WinForms application, and am attempting to use the MVP pattern for the first time.

I have a UserControl that implements an interface.  I am receiving errors compiling because the designer file (.designer.cs) does not implement the members of the interface that it's User Control does.

I apologize for this being a dumb question, but how does one get around this?  I'm assuming it's not standard practice to implement all interface members in the designer code as well as the regular code-behind?

Comment: Please provide the code where you implement the interface, and the exception thrown, exception message and typically the exception stack trace.  Otherwise everyone here will be mostly in the dark about your issue.

Comment: Do not remove the inheritance from `UserControl` - just *add* your interface. The designer file is a partial class, so it's compiled as one class with your own code - it's almost the same as just pasting the contents of the designer class into your class.

Comment: Post the code. I'm sure your UserControl  doesn't implement the interface member (or did it wrong)

Comment: your designer is a partial class.  You can just implement the interface in the other partial class in the code behind.  Your problem is elsewhere, in that you aren't implementing the interface correctly, or your designer is unable to work correctly with your code behind

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, I'm an idiot and figured it out.  I forgot to implement the set accessor defined in my interface.  I appreciate the responses.